Submitting a form from a website to an external Kali Linux server to run a python script
As part of my school project, I am trying to create an automated vulnerability tester website which takes in a user input as URL and this URL will be submitted over to a kali back end, which will run a python scripts using os.system("command") commands.
However I am having an issue with understanding the networking of this,
How can I setup my form, to submit the URL to my kali back end hosted on the cloud,
And how can my kali back end receive this information from the website?
So far on youtube abd stackoverflow, the suggestions have been to use flask, but this works only if the front and and back end are local right?

TLDR 1. I have a form in a website that takes URL as user input
2. I have an external Linux back end.
3. I want to send this form data to the Linux back end, and automatically execute a script with the URL as parameter.
How can I do this?

The only way for your Kali to receive the contents of the form is if it is itself the web server or the (deciphering) proxy (such as squid). Otherwise, your browser will simply refuse to send the data, because it's considered Cross-Site-Scripting (XSS). Another way is to listen with tcpdump, but that will fail if there's any form of encryption.
